# How to get access to servers?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, xbox-one, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

My son bought Minecraft for his xbox one on a disc. I have also bought minecraft but I purchased digitally. I have the servers option to play all the games (cake wars, etc.). However he doesn't. He has a gold membership (thought maybe an update would be needed).

How he can access servers?

Comment: @PausePause What do you mean by "console refers to console-commands"? The tag [tag:minecraft-console] refers to a game, as described by its tag wiki, and should be present on this question because one of the answers is "you need to update to bedrock edition"

Comment: You’re right. I was misremembering [this meta post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14800/pocket-edition-is-now-bedrock-why-pe-is-not-a-synonym-when-should-the-pe-tag-b) which states “ No tag minecraft-console at all, it only causes confusion between minecraft-legacy-console and minecraft-bedrock-edition. Same reasons as for minecraft. There are still posts that were asked recently of which I have no idea which of the two they are about. And some people even use it for commands questions, because they "open a console".”

Comment: [minecraft-console] is for the Legacy Console Edition by 4J Studios, [minecraft-bedrock-edition] is for the Bedrock edition by Xbox Game Studios. Because this question was posted after the release of Bedrock for Xbox One (September 20, 2017), OP is probably using the most up to date version of Bedrock at that time. Also, as far as I know, LCE can't connect to external servers.

Comment: "Gold membership" sounds suspiciously like a scam… As far as I know you can only have bought the game or not bought the game, there are no tiers. At least that's how it works for MCJava.

Answer (score 1):

You need to buy the new Minecraft digitally, unless your son has played for 5+ hours between Sep. 2016 and Sep. 2017. Since servers seem not to be available, check for updates. If after any updates (if there are any), it still doesn't work, it means you do not meet the criteria and must buy the digital version.

> If you own the disc version of Minecraft: Xbox One Edition and you
>   have played for at least 5 hours or purchased an item between
>   September 2016 and September 2017, you will also receive a digital
>   copy of Minecraft under Ready to install. This offer is valid until
>   January 31, 2018, after which time you will need to purchase a digital
>   version of Minecraft.

[Source](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/games/game-titles/minecraft-better-together-update)

Answer (score 0):

You should just turn the console on when he goes to bed and open a new world, a lot of things will turn off but as long as the controller is plugged in to the Xbox it won't turn off and pause the game. He'll be able to download the update in the morning.

Answer (score -2):

He has to play for 5 hours and he can download the update for free off the store.